# Zend Server: allowing a workspace to be run through apache outside of apache2/htdocs?

Tags: apache-2.2

i am currently having trouble using Zend/Apache2/htdocs as my workspace in eclipse, so i was wondering if i could use another workspace and still have apache run my local website there.

is that possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the DocumentRoot setting in Apache. That way it will know where to look for your files.

Typically this is in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Thanks,

Matt.